# Error in Build After InAppPurchase Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/Sabasoft Developer/Downloads/tools_r25.2.3-windows\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "D:\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[

]
stdout[
Warning: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:12, D:\unity projects\Pizza maker\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GooglePlay\AndroidManifest.xml:3] Main manifest has  but library uses targetSdkVersion='24'
]
exit code: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Update Java SdK
2. Update Android SdK
3. Check target in  menifest file and Unity editor. Both should be same.
4. Remove duplicate .jar under plugins folder if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a library somewhere in your code (possibly something for GooglePlay?). The library has a **manifest.xml** file that is likely located in a folder called **plugin** or one of its subfolders.

The **manifest** is the file used by android to describe the app: how it starts, what permissions it has, and so on.

Any android project in unity will include a default manifest.xml file. This file is edited by unity with some info relative to you game (the name, and the **target version**, are part of it).

Now, the libraries you include in your project might need different options and values in the manifest, so Unity libraries for android usually come with another manifest.xml file. This will will be automatically **merged with the default one** by unity at build time.

Usually, it goes well, the additional line in the manifest from the library get added to the default manifest.

But in your case, there is a conflict between these manifests. The **target version** is specified both in the library and in your project. So unity can't resolve it.

To fix this, use a target version for your project that is the same or higher than the one of the library. Edit your target version under **player settings**